# How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter Java 11

Tags: java, jwt, java-11

I have an API that receives a JWT token for authorization.

Once it starts the process of working with the token to authenticate it throws this error:
`Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter`

I read that in Java 11 they removed the java.xml.bind library from the JDK. I added these two dependencies as suggested in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception):
`implementation "jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.0"` and
`implementation "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:3.0.0"`.

Also tried `implementation "jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.0"` and `implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:3.0.0'`.

But I still get the same error and I cannot find any other solution to this.

I use Java 11 and Spring boot 2.6.6.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community: Not necessary. The question is fine.

Answer (score 7):

i solved this problem by removing old jjwt 0.9.1
and add these

```
implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.5'
runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.5'
runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.5'
```

Answer (score 4):

As @andréootide said JJWT needs DatatypeConverter from javax.xml.bind.....
I solved my problem by adding

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use version 2.x of those dependencies. In version 3.x, the leading prefix `javax` was replaced by `jakarta`. The same occurred for other Java EE / Jakarta EE APIs.

Comment: But in the first option where I used version 3.x I used jakarta.

Comment: Yes, there are three types for the Java EE and Jakarta EE APIs: the first use groupIds that starts with `javax`. Those are all Java EE. Then these were handed over to the Jakarta project. These use groupIds that start with `jakarta`. The first version of these APIs still use package prefix `javax`, probably for easier transition. Later versions changed the package prefix to `jakarta`.

Comment: Yes, but we already had the jakarta V. 3.X dependency so unfortunately I cannot downgrade the library version. 

So using this one jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.0 should be fine right?

Comment: Unfortunately, that comes with packages with the `jakarta` prefix. You'll still get the same error. Since you can only get one version of a library, you probably need to use the old dependency instead: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api. If you need an implementation and you still need the version 3 Glassfish dependency, try version 2.x of https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl.

Comment: I found that we use external library io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1 Base64Codec class to parse the encoded token. Inside the class it calls javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter from javax.xml.bind:javx-api:2.3.1.

Maybe that's why it doesn't work changing the jakarta version because it anyways uses this one. Because searching the libraries I have the DatatypeConverter class in jakarta 3.X but it uses the one from javax.

Comment: This solved my issue with docx4j / docx-stamper relying on JAXB

Answer (score 0):

As @Ballo Ibrahima also said, however since all Java EE project packages have been migrated to Jakarta, I solved my problem by adding this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```