# How to Resolve this error Full authentication is required to access this resource?

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, jwt, access-token

While hit login url in postman the above error occurs ..the concept is want to generate jwt token using cookies .am new to Springboot ..please help me to get out from this issue..The configuration  am using was SpringBoot version:3.0.1 and java version 17

here i attach the configuration files  used .

AuthEntryPointJwt.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());

        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

        final Map<String, Object> body = Map.of("status", HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "error", "Unauthorized",
                "message", authException.getMessage(), "path", request.getServletPath());

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), body);
    }
}
```

AuthTokenFilter.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import com.midfin.erp.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl;

import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = parseJwt(request);
            if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String jwt = jwtUtils.getJwtFromCookies(request);
        return jwt;
    }
}
JwtUtils.java:

import java.util.Date;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseCookie;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils;
import com.midfin.erp.impl.UserDetailsImpl;
import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.UnsupportedJwtException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.Cookie;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;




@Component
public class JwtUtils {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Value("${jwt.expirationMs}")
    private int jwtExpirationMs;

    @Value("${jwt.cookieName}")
    private String jwtCookie;

    public String getJwtFromCookies(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, jwtCookie);
        if (cookie != null) {
            return cookie.getValue();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ResponseCookie generateJwtCookie(UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal) {
        String jwt = generateTokenFromUsername(userPrincipal.getUsername());
        System.out.println(jwt);
        ResponseCookie cookie = ResponseCookie.from(jwtCookie, jwt).path("/api").maxAge(24 * 60 * 60).httpOnly(true)
                .build();
        return cookie;
    }

    public ResponseCookie getCleanJwtCookie() {
        ResponseCookie cookie = ResponseCookie.from(jwtCookie, null).path("/api").build();
        return cookie;
    }

    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }

    public String generateTokenFromUsername(String username) {
        return Jwts.builder().setSubject(username).setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationMs))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret).compact();
    }
}

WebSecurityConfig.java:

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchy;
import org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.midfin.erp.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl;



@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()

                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
        RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
        String hierarchy = "ROLE_ADMIN  > ROLE_USER";
        roleHierarchy.setHierarchy(hierarchy);
        return roleHierarchy;
    }
}

UserDetailsImpl.java:

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import com.midfin.erp.domain.UserPrivilege;
import com.midfin.erp.domain.UserRole;
import com.midfin.erp.domain.Users;

import lombok.Data;



@Data
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long userId;

    private String username;

    private String email;

    private String fullName;

    private String mobileNumber;

    private String password;

    private boolean locked;

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public UserDetailsImpl(Long userId, String username, String email, String password, String fullName,
            String mobileNumber, Boolean locked, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.locked = locked;
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    public static UserDetailsImpl build(Users user) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new UserDetailsImpl(user.getUserId(), user.getUsername(), user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(),
                user.getMobileNumber(), user.getFullName(), user.getIslocked(), authorities);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return !this.locked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    private List<String> getPrivileges(Collection<UserRole> roles) {

        List<String> privileges = new ArrayList<>();
        List<UserPrivilege> collection = new ArrayList<>();
        for (UserRole role : roles) {
            privileges.add(role.getName());
            collection.addAll(role.getPrivileges());
        }
        for (UserPrivilege item : collection) {
            privileges.add(item.getName());
        }
        return privileges;
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> privileges) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String privilege : privileges) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(privilege));
        }
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

}
UserDetailsServiceImpl.java:

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.midfin.erp.domain.Users;
import com.midfin.erp.repo.UserRepo;



@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepo userRepo;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Users user = userRepo.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with username: " + username));
        return UserDetailsImpl.build(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at your logs, you'll see something like this: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter

This is because the io.jsonwebtoken dependency uses javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter, but in spring version 3 it no longer uses the name javax but jakarta

As mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/a/75203778/9718846 you need to add the 0.11.5 dependencies. For maven, the answer is here : https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#features